# django specific user content/data

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to display specific content/data based on a logged in user. I want to display only their info. This is what I've tried but I can't get it to work.

**views.py**

```
class DemoView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'demographics/demographics.html'

  def get(self, request):
    demos = Demographics.objects.filter(user=request.user)  
    context = {
        'demos': demos,
    }

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Demographics(models.Model):
 first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
 middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
 last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

**HTML**

```
{% if demos %}
{% for demographics in demos %}
   <p>First Name</p> {{ demographics.first_name }}
{% endfor %}


{% else %}
<h3>you dont have demo yet</h3>

{% endif %}
```

I feel like I'm close. What am I missing?

Comment: whats error or response?

Comment: no errors per se, i just dont get any results.     this is what im doing in the HTML template         {% if demos %}
    {% for demographics in demos %}
       <p>First Name</p> {{ demographics.first_name }}
    {% endfor %}


 {% else %}
    <h3>you dont have demo yet</h3>

{% endif %}

Comment: Are you logged In?

Comment: yes. logged in and verified there are objects for demographics in DB.

Comment: @jtktyler `print demos` in views, and check whether the list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

full Answer:

Views.py

```
class DemoView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'demographics/demographics.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        demos = Demographics.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get (username=request.user))
        context = {
            'demos': demos,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

HTML:

```
{% if demos %}
{% for demographics in demos %}
   <p>First Name</p> {{ demographics.first_name }}
{% endfor %}


{% else %}
<h3>you dont have demo yet</h3>

{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^test/', views.DemoView.as_view()),
```

admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Demographics)
```

models.py

```
class Demographics(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

Go to django admin, check your objects, and make sure you're logged in to the account that has demographic objects associated with it.

The above setup works for me, if it doesn't work for you, you're most likely logged in as a user which doesn't have any demographic objects associated with it.

Also, don't name your models as plural, it should be Demographic, because it is a representation of one object. When you filter in views, you name the variable demographics (plural), because the query returns more than one object.

Comment: That still returns my "you dont have demo yet" message. no effect. I have a DB browser and have confirmed I have saved objects to test. any ideas?

Comment: @jtktyler test it with a string, see if a string is rendered, hence `'demos': "test string",` and in your template `{{ demos }}`.

Comment: yes, i can now see "test string" (oddly enough it prints it about 10 times down the page for some reason??) but i see it none the less. What does this tell me?

Comment: @jtktyler It basically means there is no issues with rendering. Please check my update.

Comment: AlmostABeginner. Man , i really appreciate all your effort! thanks so much for working on my issue!     I tried everything you listed and im still not getting any results on the page. I think what you said about being a user w/o objects is correct. When i check the database, it says user_id is NULL. i must not be saving the data as a specific user when i submit the form. any idea how i can fix it? again, thanks for all you've already done!!!!

Comment: @jtktyler How are you creating the Demographics object? Easy way is to just do it in default django admin panel, there you will be able to create new Demographics objects, or edit existing ones and just add a user to the user field.

Answer (score 0):

I think debugging using `pdb` will help why the get is not rendering the data properly but if you know how django `templateview` class handles the context data, you have to modify the code a bit. Here I used `get_context_data` instead of `get` and hope this time it will work.

```
class DemoView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'demographics/demographics.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DemoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        demos = Demographics.objects.filter(user=self.request.user) 
        context['demos'] = demos
        return context
```

Also you can check if the table `Demographics` has the data for the selected user.

Comment: hmm, this throws an error for "HomePageView"... im thinking that was just a genric placeholder you used that i should be replacing with something specific to my application? it also doesnt like "request" from "user=request.user", for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that you are filtering out all answers from your queryset because the content of request.user is not quite a match for a 'user' object. I don't know why they wouldn't match, but in my code I use:

```
User.objects.get(username = request.user.username)
```